# Как заменить текст по нажатию на элемент аккордеона?

Tags: jquery, текст, замена, события, click

Нужно изменить код скрипта так, чтобы по нажатию на элемент аккордеона "Текст 2", находящийся во втором теге `span` менялся на "Какой-то другой текст" при развороте контента. И когда контент сворачивается "Какой-то другой текст" должен опять меняться на "Текст 2".

```js
$(".accordeon dd").hide().prev().click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".accordeon").find("dd").not(this).slideUp().prev().removeClass("active");
$(this).next().not(":visible").slideDown().prev().addClass("active");
  
});
```

```css
.accordeon dl dt span:nth-child(2) {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordeon">
  <dl>
    <dt><span>Текст 1</span> <span>Текст 2</span></dt>
    <dd>Какой-то текст</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: чушь какая-то, текст 2 разве не заголовок таба? зачем туда тулить текст вкладки?

Comment: Вы не поняли, "Какой-то текст" и "Какой-то другой текст" - разные вещи.
Мне нужно изменить "Текст 2" на любой другой. И чтобы он менялся с "Текст 2" на другой и с другого на "Текст 2", в зависимости от того раскрыт аккордеон или нет